# Snake game setting up fruit spots

Tags: java, user-interface

So I'm making a snake game, I have the controls, and basic gui.
The problem is that when trying to paint the fruit, it won't stop painting. What I want it to do is when the player collides with the fruit it adds score. To do that I need the fruit first to only paint once, how?

Basic paintComponent.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
        g.drawRect(fruit.getXLoc(), fruit.getYLoc(), 10, 10);
        fruitCollected(); //method saying if you go into a certain range of the fruit add score;
        g.drawString("Score: " + score + fruit.getXLoc() + fruit.getYLoc(), 150, 150);
        if(gameover() == true) {
            this.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        }

}
```

In another class I have the getXLoc and getXLoc

```
public class FruitLocation {
int xSize = 580; //x and y boundary for placing fruit
int ySize = 350;
int xLoc;
int yLoc;
    public int getXLoc() {
    int xLoc = (int) (Math.random() * xSize) ;
    return xLoc;
}
public int getYLoc() {
    int yLoc = (int) (Math.random() * ySize);
    return yLoc;
}
```

}

Comment: Are you clearing the screen before you draw each time?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not the problem, it the "fruit square" just keeps moving to the random places, its not a screen clearing problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic problem is you calling methods within the `paint` method that will cause a `repaint` event to be generated, again and again and...

Start by removing the calls to `setBackground`

Next, don't change the state of the fruit outside of the "main-loop", that is, don't do...

```
public int getXLoc() {
   int xLoc = (int) (Math.random() * xSize) ;
   return xLoc;
}
```

Because a paint cycle may be caused by any number of reasons, many of which you don't control, you want these methods to return a concrete value.  They should be update as part of your "main-loop" logic and you will need to supply appropriate methods to allow this to occur.

On a side note, you shadowing your variables.  What I mean is, when you can the `xLoc` value in the `getXLoc` method, it is not changing the `xLoc` instance variable of the `Fruit` class, for example...

```
int xLoc;
public int getXLoc() {
    int xLoc = (int) (Math.random() * xSize) ;
    ^--- Shadowing the instance variable...
    return xLoc;
}
```

Comment: Ok so how would you get new "cords" everytime a action occurs?

Comment: @ImGone98 This will depend on how you are updating your view, but we don't have enough to go on to know how this is done.  Painting does just that, it paints the view, it should not be used to modify the state of the model

Comment: I got it, it initiates the cords with just plain variables then when the player collides with the fruit it "recreates" those variables with random cords and any time the player collides it recreates the cords. Thank you, sometimes it just takes trying to think about things like this in different ways.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it's jumping is because you're drawing the rectangle using the `getXLoc` and `getYLoc` methods. These methods, however, generate a new random number each time. Instead, set the x and y locations to a value in the `Fruitlocation` constructor, and make a new method that generates new random values. The code for `getXLoc` should look as follows:

```
public int getXLoc(){
    return xLoc;
}
```